# Pass value from HTML page form to a CGI program

Tags: perl, cgi, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a simple program that will get the content of the webpage for the sake of my assignment.

Right now I create a very simple HTML page that will let the user enter a URL.

```
<html>
<head><title>URL page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="cgi-bin/b1.cgi" method="GET">
        Enter the URL you want to see <input type="text" name="passing" size=40>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

so I just want to pass the url to my CGI program that I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use LWP::Simple;
use CGI;
use HTML::HeadParser;

#my $pass = $cgi->param('passing');

$URL = get ("$passing");

$head = HTML::HeadParser->new;

$head->parse("$URL");

print "This is the Title of the page" . $head->header('Title') . "\n\n";

print $head->header('X-Meta-Description') . "\n\n";

print $head->header('X-Meta-Keywords') . "\n\n";

print $head->header('Content-Type') . "\n\n";

print $head->header('Content-Language') . "\n\n";

exit;
```

So from the above code as you can see if I can get the value that pass from the `GET` method to the line where it say `URL = get();` then I can get the content.

I tried some approch like `my $pass = $cgi->param('passing');` but it gives me an error about `param`

Any suggestion would be so much appreciated.

Comment: You need $cgi = CGI->new; first to create the $cgi object. See http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: @UncleO that answered my question thanks! Please post an answer so I can accepted the answer.